# What should I do if a misleading edit gets approved?

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits

I've just rejected a [suggested edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/6769107) because the introduced tag has nothing to do with the question. I have also left a comment for edit's author but after all the edit got an approval.

Should I remove the misleading tag anyway or accept the community's will? It now suggests that the OP is asking about `log4j` which he is not.

Comment: You should probably propose another edit and remove those irrelevant tags. Wait, you're over 2k, you don't have to propose edits.

Comment: I don't want to misuse my _powers_ ;-) so I thought I'd better ask.

Comment: I guess it got approved since log4j is the most popular logging framework (AFAIK), and logging is in the scope of the function. But a question tagged log4j along with an answer which basically says *use log4j* (without actually answering the question but that's another matter), doesn't feel right.

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski that's the point. The person who answerd it also introduced the tag.

Comment: @t3chb0t Banging a question in shape, to fit ones answer is abusive. Roll back the edit.

Comment: Ok @Matt has just anticipated my plan... but now I know what to do in future ;-)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tags say what the question **is** about, not what it is **not** about. If the question is clearly not about that tag, it would be best to remove it.

About the answerer adding tags: Answers *answer* questions. The *answer* was about [log4j](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/log4j), but not the *question*. The *question* should not have the tag.

Comment: I agree with this, and I think it's important to add that sometimes you need to read between the lines when tagging questions. Take for instance an example question: "How can I increment the number on this web page when it is clicked?", tagged HTML. Now the question isn't technically about JavaScript, but any useful answer is going to involve it. Basically, tags are about helping people find and sort through posts, so be smart about tagging!

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister: Would you claim an answer involving a server round-trip would necessarily be invalid for such a question?  I don't think that [tag:javascript] should be added in such a case.  The fact that you think it is necessary might just be answerer-bias (you honestly believe it is the best approach, which led you to answer, but that doesn't make you correct).  Same instance as the question here.

Comment: @BenVoigt I get what you're saying. If the OP's question left room for it to be reasonably interpreted as a server-side question, then it would make more sense not to add the tag. However, if the user was asking about how to increment a number on a static HTML page, and didn't mention anything about a server-side setup or code, then I do think that a JavaScript tag would be appropriate. It would be different from the question here, where there are possible answers that make sense and don't involve `log4j`. Ex: I would tag a question with CSS if it asks how to use a custom font in HTML.